# Bot is down but the app is hosted successfully on heroku

Tags: kotlin, gradle, heroku

I am trying to host a bot by programmers hangout which is polly on heroku it uses gradle i've did every task stage and all and also hosted the bot on heroku the process went successfully great no errors at all. but the bot is still down where i've also added the token of it in config vars. it using gradle and in build.gradle.kts
i've provided the task to make it work and also in the build file there also and also in procfile i've provided the worker of java -jar to the path of the build/lib/.jar file

but there is Procfile error

```
Starting process with command `java -jar /build/libs/Polly-master-1.0.0.jar`
```

this is was there in the procfile

```
worker: java -jar /build/libs/Polly-master-1.0.0.jar
```

[file system of build folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqX03.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. That first paragraph is a giant run-on without any formatting and is therefore very hard to read.

Comment: What makes you think there is an error with your `Procfile`? It looks like Heroku is running the command you asked it to run. And what do you mean by "down"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: by **down** i mean bot is offline and i think there is an error this one is showing when i view logs `Error: Unable to access jarfile /build/libs/Polly-master-1.0.0.jar`